# Orbit size of an element

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and assume that $G$ is acting over a set $X$. Let $c$ be some element of $X$, is there any relationship among the size of the orbit of $c$ under the action of $H$ and the size of the orbit of $c$ under the action of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $G$ is a finite group: If $G_c$ is the stabilizer of $c$, then
$$ |Gc| = |G|/|G_c| $$
and
$$ |Hc| = |H|/|H\cap G_c| = |HG_c|/|G_c| $$
so
$$ \frac{|Gc|}{|Hc|} = \frac{|G|}{|HG_c|}. $$

**EDIT:** For the infinite case asked for in the comment, we can do this: By choosing representatives $gc$ for each element of the orbit of $c$, the map $(gc,s) \mapsto gs$ establishes a one-to-one correspondence showing
$$ |Gc|\cdot |G_c| = |G|. $$
Similarly (using choice), we have
$$ |Hc| \cdot |G_c| = |HG_c|. $$
Then we can say
$$ |Gc|\cdot |HG_c| = |Gc|\cdot |Hc|\cdot |G_c| = |Hc|\cdot |G|. $$
I don't immediately see a way around making arbitrary choices, though.

Comment: I am actually not assuming that $G$ is finite. But I was hoping the same could be concluded with cardinal operations, i.e. $|HG_{c}| | G_{c}|= |G||H_{c}|.